# Iterating through a column of pandas dataframe that has time values and return seconds

Tags: python

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Time:
16:45:15
16:45:31
16:45:59
.
.
```

I want to convert these times values into seconds and I did the following:

```
def get_sec(arr):
    h,m,s = arr.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

sec_val = []
for i in range(len(df['Time'])):
    sec_val.append(get_sec(df['Time'][i]))
```

and it gives this error:

```
'datatime.time' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Although if I used the same code for one string it works, but when I use it in a for loop it gives this error, any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [24]: df['TimeInSeconds'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x : x.hour *3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second )
```

Looks like your column is type datetime.time so you can directly use it's attributes like hour , minute , second rather than doing string split as above. hope it helps :)

Edit:

In case of string we can convert all in time objects
then use the apply

```
import datetime

In [38]: df['Time' ] = df['Time'].astype(str).apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S' ).time() )

In [39]: df['TimeInSeconds'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x : x.hour *3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second )
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives 'str' object has no attribute 'hour'!